# how to convert YYYY to yy format date:year()

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I am using stylesheet template version 1.0 and i need the current date to show in mm/yy, so far i have got <xsl:value-of select="date:month-in-year()"/> / <xsl:value-of select="date:year()"/>
which outputs 11 / 2020. this is correct but i need the the year to show as '20' instead of 2020. im new to programming, so any help will be greatly appreciated!

thanks in advance

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your processor supports the `date:year()` extension function, then you can use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(date:year(), 3)"/>
```

or:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(date:year() mod 100, '00')"/>
```